# Project Projection

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

### The Project

[image: Project Header]

You and a co-worker have been assigned to complete a web application.

The client wants to know how many hours the project will take to complete - the minimum.

**Your Puzzle Task**
You need to figure out how many hours the project will take.

### Supporting Data

The project consists of the following:

1. User Interface Design
2. Database Design
3. Backend PHP Development

Each task takes 20 hours to complete.

Oh yeah, the boss wants only one person to work on a project's task at a time - meaning you and your coworker can't both code, or both do front-end work at the same time.

### Hours To Complete

**What's the minumum number of hours this project will take to complete?**

*There is only one correct answer*

Comment: Some thoughts:  (As a developer we don't proceed to further work until front-end is completed because then only we know what fields needed to be in db and all . If two people are doing work simuntenoulsy on different module then also they have to coordinate with each other that will take time)

Comment: lol. okay, okay, Swati you got me there! I tried to put a tech twist on this classic permutation problem. But a valid observation! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 30 hours.
>  first 10 hours: task 1&2, next 10 hours: task 2&3, next 10 hours: task 3&1.
>  (Or am I missing something?)